# I have a valid usa B1/B2 visa in my maiden name on my cancelled passport. Can I still use it to enter the US?

Tags: visas, usa, passports, b1-b2-visas

I had a USA B1/B2 visa on my cancelled passport which is valid until 2020. I had made a new passport with my husband's name and new address after marriage. Do I need to apply for the visa again to visit the USA ?

Comment: What is a cancelled passport? Is it expired?

Comment: No when i made a new passport they stamped the previous one cancelled

Comment: @phoog Would it be an idea to mark the other one as a duplicate of this one, considering the much better answer this one now has?

Comment: @J.Constantine I would leave that decision to the moderators.

Comment: @J.Constantine The answer seem more or less identical to me and the answer to the other question contains more direct quotation from official documents than this one.

Answer (score 4):

[You can't nor should transfer the visa to the new passport.](http://www.ustraveldocs.com/in/in-gen-faq.asp#qlistb1b2_4) What you should do is **travel with both passports, and a copy of your marriage certificate**, when seeking entry into the USA:

> #### Q.4 I currently hold a valid B-1/B-2 visa, which is in my maiden name, in my old passport. I wish to transfer this visa to my new passport, which is in my married name. What is the procedure?
>
> U.S. visas cannot be transferred from one passport to another. You can travel to the United States with both passports as well as your marriage certificate, or you can apply for a new visa.

In addition, you should not try to remove the visa from one passport with the purpose of sticking it on the new passport.

However, you should obtain a different visa if your purpose of travel in the USA has changed since you applied for the B1/B2 visa.

Comment: If i donot apply for the visa again . Carrying both the passport and marriage certificate will solve the purpose?