# Applying for new visa when having same visa in maiden name is considered as renewal or new Visa?

Tags: visas, usa, visa-renewals

I have a valid  US visa with my maiden name. My full name has changed after marriage. I have got a new passport with my new name.
I have to travel and its suggested to apply for a new visa.
On the new visa application appointment scheduling shall I say YES to the Questions that says 'Do you have a valid visa?'

Saying yes, it is considered as renewal.
Can I apply for renewal visa in my new name on basis of my valid maiden name visa?

Comment: @Sneha You should check the entry requirements of the country(ies) you’re planning to visit, but typically travelling with both old and new passports plus your marriage certificate is acceptable. For example see https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69622/i-have-a-valid-usa-b1-b2-visa-in-my-maiden-name-on-my-cancelled-passport-can-i

Comment: The answer is different for every country. You need to specify which country you are referring to.

Comment: This is for US Visa

Comment: Thanks for editing your question to clarify it. A vote has started to reopen the question, which might take a short while. However, it does seem that your question is answered by the one that Traveller linked to.

Comment: @DavidRicherby The USA Department of State **recommends** you apply for a new visa.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. A name change does not invalidate a USA visa and from their own language you can continue to use it. They [recommend you apply for a new visa with a name change](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/frequently-asked-questions/about-basics.html) just for ease of travel.

> If your name has legally changed through marriage, divorce, or a court
>   ordered name change, you will need to obtain a new passport.  Once you
>   have a new passport, the Department of State **recommends** that you apply
>   for a new U.S. visa **to make it easier** for you to travel to and from
>   the United States.

[Executive Order Suspends (at Least Parts of) the Visa Interview Waiver “Dropbox” Program](https://www.cilawgroup.com/news/2017/02/02/executive-order-suspends-least-parts-interview-waiver-dropbox-visa-stamp-program/)

However note that via [Executive Order 13769](https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2017/02/01/2017-02281/protecting-the-nation-from-foreign-terrorist-entry-into-the-united-states), President Trump suspended a good portion of the Visa Interview Waiver “Dropbox” Program which is same as visa renewal.

This means many people who hitherto could just renew their visas without interviews are now subjected to interviews thus be prepared with all the necessary documents to be interviewed in case you are called up.

**Choose YES**. They will make the determination if they want to interview you.