# USA visa validity in case of surname change

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas

If an individual from India holds a tourist visa for the USA, changes due to marriage, and gets a new passport in the new name, does the visa remain valid, or are there specific procedures or actions required to ensure its continued validity under the new name?

Comment: when you say "undergoes a name change" do you mean "gets a new passport with the new name in it"? or does the person intend to travel on the old visa and old passport while answering to the new name in conversation or perhaps having some other documents in the new name?

Comment: no. she got married and she took surname of her husband. so updated passport will have her name and her husbands surname. its common in India.

e.g if her maiden name is sima patel and marries roshan kotak

in that case her name changes to sima kotak

Comment: yes, it is common in many places to change your name, but many people don't get new passports right away and travel under their own name. Especially for a honeymoon trip there isn't time to get a new passport, but it is often done even for a few years after the wedding.

Comment: related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/123556/46

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Applying for new visa when having same visa in maiden name is considered as renewal or new Visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/123556/applying-for-new-visa-when-having-same-visa-in-maiden-name-is-considered-as-rene)

Comment: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69622/i-have-a-valid-usa-b1-b2-visa-in-my-maiden-name-on-my-cancelled-passport-can-i  this helped

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I have a valid usa B1/B2 visa in my maiden name on my cancelled passport. Can I still use it to enter the US?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69622/i-have-a-valid-usa-b1-b2-visa-in-my-maiden-name-on-my-cancelled-passport-can-i)

Comment: yes @Midavalo. you can mark this as duplicate